# Alert dialog items are not at the same height

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog that its items are all in the same height besides the last one that is higher, and I have no idea why. I tried to set it with:

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80 ));
```

but it didn't help, the last one is still higher... any ideas?

[image]

This is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the code in the Activity:

```
            final CharSequence[] items;
            List<String> listItems;

                listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

                listItems.add("Remind me in a week");
                listItems.add("Set a reminder");
                listItems.add("Save permanently");
                listItems.add("Delete now");
                items = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);

final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("When do you want to delete " + name + "?" )
        .setView(view)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 4, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: It is not the hight of last item - it is distance between button and last item of list.

Comment: OK, thanks. do you know I fix that?

Comment: I can try - you can post your layout and simple way to reproduce

Comment: I added it now to my question... Thanks!

Comment: is it all how do you add your items?

Comment: post the way how do you add new items.

Comment: ok give me a few minutes I will check what I can do with this

Comment: I'd tell you to use height as `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` and if height seems smaller than you want, then add some top and bottom padding to it programmatically.

Comment: @Mor remove setView(view) it is not neccsary

Comment: @Mor I am glad that I could help you Please accept my solution :)

Comment: I tried to mark it as usful too but I don't have enough reputation yet... @Apurva - the WRAP_CONTENT didn't work but thanks to you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `setView(view)` method. It is not necessary. You just put empty `LinearLayout` which is redundant on this dialog.